# What are some examples of inner endomorphisms?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ be an algebraic structure. If $t$ is an $n+1$-ary term, then let $L_{t,a_{1},...,a_{n}}:X\rightarrow X$ be the mapping defined by
$L_{t,a_{1},...,a_{n}}(x)=t(a_{1},...,a_{n},x)$. We say that a $n+1$-ary term $t$ is endomorphic if $L_{t,a_{1},...,a_{n}}$ is an endomorphism whenever $a_{1},...,a_{n}\in X$. The endomorphisms of the form $L_{t,a_{1},...,a_{n}}$ are known as inner endomorphisms.

What are some examples of inner endomorphisms? What are some examples of endomorphic terms?

Let me give a couple examples to start things off:

1. Every inner automorphism of a group is an inner endomorphism.
2. If $(X,\wedge,\vee)$ is a distributive lattice and $a\in X$, then the mapping $x\mapsto a\wedge x$ is an inner endomorphism. If $(X,\leq)$ is a Heyting algebra, then the mapping $a\mapsto a*x$ is always an inner endomorphism.
3. The notion of an inner endomorphism is closely related to self-distributivity. If $(X,*)$ is an algebraic structure that satisfies $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$, then the mapping $x\mapsto a*x$ is always an inner endomorphism.
4. If $(X,+)$ is an abelian group, then the mapping $x\mapsto n\cdot x$ is always an inner endomorphism. If $V$ is a vector space, then scalar multiplication is always an inner endomorphism.
5. If $G$ is a group, then the constant mapping $x\mapsto e$ is always an inner endomorphism. There are similar inner endomorphisms on different structures like vector spaces, lattices, and in other structures.
6. Any endomorphism can be made into an inner endomorphism. Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is an algebraic structure and $\phi:(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow (X,\mathcal{F})$ is an endomorphism. Then the mapping $\phi$ is a (rather trivial) inner endomorphism of the structure $(X,\mathcal{F},\phi)$.

Comment: There are also rigid structures, with the identity map as both a trivial term and a trivial endomorphism.  Of course, functionally complete algebras provide inner endomorphisms.  I dimly recall in study of interpretation of varieties the notion of first-order definability of the maps involved.  Maybe there is work on self-interpretability that may give more examples.  Gerhard "Fewer Operations Means More Endomorphisms?" Paseman, 2017.10.01.

Comment: Don't know if this will give you other examples, but a paper of George Bergman's has a title that seems appropriate: "An inner automorphism is only an inner automorphism, but an endomorphism can be something strange", Pub. Math. 56 (2012), 91-126; available from his webpage, at https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/inner.pdf

Comment: The paper by George Bergman is concerning a category theoretic notion of an inner endomorphism which does not necessarily coincide with the algebraic notion of an inner endomorphism which I have described.